# TypeError: Derived contract must override function “_beforeTokenTransfer”

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts

I am trying to implement an `ERC20` token that inherits `ERC20.sol`, `ERC20Detailed.sol`, `ERC20Burnable.sol`, `ERC20Mintable.sol`, and `ERC20Pausable.sol`.

```js
contract DemoContract is ERC20,ERC20Detailed,ERC20Burnable,ERC20Mintable, ERC20Pausable {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20Detailed("Test Token", "TEST", 18) public {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

The function `_beforeTokenTransfer` is defined in  `ERC20.sol` as follows:

```js
function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual { }
```

and in `ERC20Pausable.sol` as follows:

```js
function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual override {
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);

    require(!paused(), "ERC20Pausable: token transfer while paused");
}
```

When I try to compile my contracts using truffle framework, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Derived contract must override function "_beforeTokenTransfer". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types.

contract DemoContract is ERC20,ERC20Detailed,ERC20Burnable,ERC20Mintable, ERC20Pausable {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

I cannot seem to understand why this error occurs although override is used in the `ERC20Pausable.sol`.

Here are the new contracts after removing ERC20 from the DemoContract:

```
contract ERC20 is Context, IERC20

contract ERC20Detailed is ERC20

abstract contract ERC20Burnable is Context, ERC20

abstract contract ERC20Mintable is ERC20, MinterRole

abstract contract ERC20Pausable is ERC20, Pausable

contract DemoContract is ERC20Detailed,ERC20Burnable,ERC20Mintable, ERC20Pausable
```

However, the error still remains.

Answer (score 2):

In `contract DemoContract is ERC20,ERC20Detailed,ERC20Burnable,ERC20Mintable, ERC20Pausable`:

Each one of contracts `ERC20Detailed`, `ERC20Burnable`, `ERC20Mintable` and `ERC20Pausable` already inherits from contract `ERC20`, so you should not inherit from this contract as well.

For example, compiling the following code gives the same error as yours:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.4;

contract Foo {
    uint x;
    function func(uint _x) public virtual {
        x = _x;
    }
}

contract Foo2 is Foo {
    function func(uint _x) public virtual override {
        super.func(2*_x);
    }
}

contract Foo3 is Foo, Foo2 {
    function func(uint _x) public virtual override {
        super.func(3*_x);
    }
}
```

Which is resolves when you change `contract Foo3 is Foo, Foo2` to `contract Foo3 is Foo2`.

Note that this is not an issue in solc 0.4.x (after removing the `virtual` and `override` of course).

Comment: I modified DemoContract so it no longer inherits ERC20. However, the error contains to appear. I updated the question above to show the contract headings. Maybe I am doing something wrong there?

Comment: @user58503: Obviously, because several contracts which your contract is iheriting from, are inheriting from the same contract (`ERC20`). You're experiencing what is known as *The diamond-inheritance problem*. The typical solutions are either virtual inheritance (C++), or prohibit that altogether (Java). I'm not sure what the solution in Solidity 0.6.x is. Obviously, this wasn't a problem in previous versions. Perhaps they (chriseth) have added support for virtual inheritance, in which case, the syntax would me more or less something like `contract X is virtual Y, virtual Z`. Give it a try...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. When I completely remove `ERC20Pausable` from the DemoContract it compiles perfectly fine, although `ERC20Detailed`, `ERCBurnable`, and `ERCMintable` all inherit `ERC20`. Therefore, I do not think this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I may use above example to extend my explanation, thanks

When you have two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types you must override that function with `override(baseContract1, baseContract2)`. Foo and Foo2 need not be necessarily inheriting from each other.

Try:

```
contract Foo3 is Foo, Foo2 {
    function func(uint _x) public virtual override(Foo, Foo2) {
        super.func(3*_x);
    }
}
```